# How to return bitmap in volley library's parseNetworkResponse method?

Tags: kotlin, android-volley

I would like to request for help to resolve this issue, I need to return the bitmap type in the parseNetworkResponse method of the volley library, but I am having difficulty doing this, any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

> ```
> class ImageListRequest(
>     private val responseListener: Response.Listener<Bitmap>,
>     private val urlImage: String,
>     errorListener: Response.ErrorListener
> ): Request<Bitmap>(Method.GET,urlImage,errorListener) {
>
>     override fun parseNetworkResponse(response: NetworkResponse?): Response<Bitmap> =
>   
>         if(response?.statusCode == HTTP_OK || response?.statusCode == HTTP_NOT_MODIFIED) {
>     
>           ByteArray(response.data).run {
>                 success(
>                     ???? ,
>                     HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response)
>                 )
>             }
>         } else {
>             Response.error(VolleyError())
>         }
> }
> ```